# How to use classes from Java SDK when designing with ArgoUML?

Tags: java, uml, argouml

I want to design a Java application in UML with help of ArgoUML and would like to reuse SDK classes in it. Is such thing possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment of Sean Mickey the correct answer is to add a Java profile to the project.

[argouml-stats.tigris.org/documentation/manual-0.30/ch24s03.html](http://argouml-stats.tigris.org/documentation/manual-0.30/ch24s03.html.)

Right click on "Profile Configuration" -> "Manage Profiles..." -> "Java from Available Profiles to Active Profiles"

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just model in the SDK class.  It's annoying that it isn't already in ArgoUML, but it's not really possible for ArgoUML to know which aspects of the JDK classes you intended to view in your diagrams.

Comment: I supposed of course inclusion of already existing namespaces. Anyway you answered the question.

Comment: @Tim, I know it's not a great answer, but the problems lie in ArgoUML's inability to predict which aspects of the JDK are important to your application.  Ideally there would be a "prediction" module in ArgoUML which could "predict" how much of the JDK should be pulled in to illustrate the aspects which are interesting in relationship to your problem.  Unfortunately, nobody's managed to code up such a crystal ball... yet.

Comment: what if we avoid "predicting" and simply give a person to choose which classes he wants to use? Btw, the answer is OK for the given question :)

Comment: Well, it would be a better solution; however, I don't want to be the person who eventually adds java.lang.Object, or java.lang.Exception and then gets prompted for which of the neighboring elements should be included.  I'm sure with some skill, it could be done in a meaningful way, but for some items you might find selecting worse that just creating.

Comment: There is now a Java Profile available within ArgoUML that provides exactly the Java Profile that was originally discussed on this topic. More information is available at: http://argouml-stats.tigris.org/documentation/manual-0.30/ch24s03.html.

Comment: @SeanMickey Awesome.  I'll have to grab a copy to check it out.

Comment: @EdwinBuck I think the answer by is the better one